Relative acceleration, mechanics
Consider a system of two objects with mass $M, m$ as presented below.

Assume that there's no friction between both the surface, M and between M, m. I'm asked to find the acceleration of m, M using forces & Newton second-law approach. The solution involves using the relative acceleration of m, M but I struggle to grasp the meaning of the relative acceleration. If we consider $a_M, a_m$ as the accelerations for the corresponding masses then is it correct to understand $a_{rel} = a_m - a_M$ as the acceleration of the body with mass $m$ as if $M$ would be at rest and $m$ would slide on it in the direction $m$ is pointing to in the system's image above?
Thanks

The position vector to the mass $~m~$ is
$$R_m=R_M+R_{Mm}$$
where $~R_{Mm}~$ is the relative position between M and m.
form here with Newton second law
$$m\,a_m=m\,(a_M+a_{\rm rel})=F_m\\
M\,a_M=F_M$$
solving for $~a_{\rm rel}~$
$$a_{\rm rel}=\frac{F_M\,M-F_m\,m}{M\,m}$$
thus the relative acceleration is depending on the applied forces $~F_M~,F_m~$ and the masses $~M~,m~$
if you add $~a_M+a_{\rm rel}~$ you obtain $~a_m=\frac{F_m}{m}~$ as it should be. Or if the mass $~M >> m~$
$$a_{\rm rel}\bigg|_{M\mapsto \infty}=a_m$$

Perhaps it would help to think of relative displacement and relative velocity.
Suppose m and M are on the table. Suppose M is at $x_M = -1 \space m$ and m is at $x_m = 2 \space m$. You can say what the displacement of each object is. That is how far both objects are from you. (You are at $x = 0$). But how far are they from each other? That is their relative displacement.
Suppose the velocity of M is $v_M = 1 \space m/s$, and $v_m = 2 \space m/s$. Again you can say how fast both are traveling with respect to you. (You are at rest in these coordinates.) But how fast are they separating? How fast does an ant on M see m traveling? That is the relative velocity.
Do the same for acceleration. A force is pulling M to the left with an acceleration of $a_M = -1 \space m/s^2$. Another is pulling m to the right with an acceleration of $a_m = 3 \space m/s^2$. You know the acceleration of each with respect to you. (There are no forces on you.) But how fast does an ant on M see m accelerate. That is the relative acceleration.
I have simplified things by assuming everything is on a line. Which makes them $1$D vectors. But you can apply the same ideas when the accelerations are $2$D  or $3$D vectors.

The application for 1D is surprisingly clear to me, whereas for 2D this becomes harder for me. Would that be correct to say that the relative acceleration just “removes” the impact of M’s acceleration on m’s acceleration?

Imagine M has a northward velocity and m is at rest. Then the ant on M sees m as having a southward velocity. Imagine M is going north and m is going east. Then the ant on M sees m going south east.

I indeed understand that, but still, I am trying to understand if in that specific case I could consider $a_R$ as defined in the main post to be in the direction as if m was sliding on M in the direction corresponding to angle $\alpha$ as in the picture I provided above
